# Compare browser versions via javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

How to compare browser versions via javascript?

For example if script wants to know if user is using Firefox 3.5+

Is there any way?

Comment: Why do you want to know what browser/version the user is using?

Comment: `quirksmode.org` has an entry on that. It's pretty detailed: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code gets the version number of Firefox:

```
var FFVersion = navigator.userAgent
                  .substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox"))
                  .split("/")[1];
```

You  decide what to do with each of them:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (FFVersion < '3.5') { alert('please upgrade...') }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should employ [object/feature detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) to ensure that something will work before you apply it. From that link:

> While browser detection works well
>   enough for 90% of your visitors, some
>   obscure browsers won't be treated
>   correctly and browsers that appear
>   after you've written the page may not
>   be adequately covered either. The
>   results would be either a stream of
>   error messages or a script that isn't
>   called while the browser can easily
>   handle it. In both cases, you're
>   cheating your end users and coding
>   incorrectly.

To get the browser version, you can use the [Navigator object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp):

```
alert(navigator.appName + ' ' + navigator.appVersion);
```

Comment: in FireFox, say 54, `navigator.appVersion` is equal to `"5.0 (Windows)"` – definitely not the version of FireFox

Answer (score 1):

Use navigator.userAgent in javascript

You'll get a string like "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6"

For firefox the last number is the version.

Answer (score 0):

This fails now with Firefox getting to 10.0. Come up with a different version:

```
// Takes 2 strings "2.3.4.5" and "2.5" and returns less, equal and greater than 0
// depending which one is bigger
function compareVersions(a, b) {
  var v1 = a.split('.');
  var v2 = b.split('.');
  for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(v1.length, v2.length); i++) {
    var res = v1[i] - v2[i];
    if (res != 0)
      return res;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer, but if I'm looking at this correctly, it won't account for if one is longer than the other. Instead of doing the `Math.min`, you should maybe try `0` filling the shorter one to find the difference

Answer (score 0):

Parse version strings as float type, then compare them with if statement or whatever you want.
Here is a sample I've used for checking IE browser version:

```
if(parseFloat($.browser.version) <= 8.0)
{
    // Do whatever you want if browser version lower than equal to 8.0
}
else
{
    // Do whatever you want if browser greater than 8.0
}
```

Comment: to be noted: `jQuery.browser` was deprecated in jQuery 1.3 and removed in 1.9 (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/ for details)